# how to migrate the display template in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, display-template

I have been changed the Search Placeholder name by modifying the Control search box.HTML from display template file, I need to move my changes into another server. Please suggest me any ideas to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Using the **migration tool**, select the option to copy the **object** that include templates, master pages, and Style Library. and just migrate it to the new site 
it's very simple by using **ShareGate** tool

Comment: Thanks, Is there has any way to achieve it by code. I mean PowerShell scripts, etc) @Jishin

Answer (score 0):

How to Upload the Display Templates into SharePoint 2013 Using PowerShell:

```
##================================================================================================
 ## Description    : To do the below two items.
     #1. Upload the Display Templates into Site Collection
 ## Author        : Sathish Nadarajan
 ## Date            : 06-Oct-2015
 ##================================================================================================

 ##============================================ Setup Input Paths ===========================================================

 cls

 $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "-- Upload the Display Templates into Site Collection --"

 $StartDate = Get-Date
 Write-Host -ForegroundColor White "------------------------------------"
 Write-Host -ForegroundColor White "| Upload the Display Templates into Site Collection |"
 Write-Host -ForegroundColor White "| Started on: $StartDate |"
 Write-Host -ForegroundColor White "------------------------------------"

 $LogTime = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm
 $LogFile = ".\UploadDisplayTemplates-$LogTime.rtf"

 #start-transcript $logfile

 $scriptBase = split-path $SCRIPT:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -parent
 Set-Location $scriptBase

 $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

 function AddPowerShellSnapin()
 {
     try
     {
         Write-Host "Adding PowerShell Snap-in" -ForegroundColor Green
         # Try to get the PowerShell Snappin.  If not, then adding the PowerShell snappin on the Catch Block
         Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
     }
     catch
     {
         if($Error[0].Exception.Message.Contains("No Windows PowerShell snap-ins matching the pattern 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell' were found"))
         {
             Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
         }
     }
     Write-Host "Finished Adding PowerShell Snap-in" -ForegroundColor Green

 }

 function UploadDisplayTemplates([string]$siteUrl)
 {
     $spsite = Get-SPSite $siteUrl
     $web = $spsite.RootWeb
     $contentWebPartsDisplayTemplatesFolder = ($web).GetFolder("Content Web Parts")
     $displayTemplatesDirectory = $scriptBase + "\DisplayTemplates"
     $web.AllowUnsafeUpdates=$true;

     #For upload all files in document library from file system
     foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $displayTemplatesDirectory)
     {
          try
          {
                  $stream = [IO.File]::OpenRead($file.fullname)
                  $destUrl = $web.Url + "/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/" + $file.Name;
                  $displayTemplateFile = $web.GetFile($destUrl)

                  if($displayTemplateFile.CheckOutStatus -ne "None")
                  {
                      $contentWebPartsDisplayTemplatesFolder.files.Add($destUrl,$stream,$true)
                      $stream.close() 
                      $displayTemplateFile.CheckOut();                      
                      $displayTemplateFile.CheckIn("CheckIn by PowerShell");                         
                      $displayTemplateFile.Publish("Publish by PowerShell");                         

                      $displayTemplateFile.Update();        
                      $web.Update();

                      Write-Host $file.Name " Display Template Page uploaded on $web site" -ForegroundColor Green  

                  }
                  else
                  {
                      $displayTemplateFile.CheckOut();
                      try
                      {
                         $contentWebPartsDisplayTemplatesFolder.Files.Add($destUrl,$stream,$true)
                      }
                      catch
                      {
                         Write-Host $_
                      }
                      $stream.close()                             
                      $displayTemplateFile.CheckIn("CheckIn by PowerShell");                         
                      $displayTemplateFile.Publish("Publish by PowerShell");                         

                      $displayTemplateFile.Update();        
                      $web.Update();


                      Write-Host $file.Name " Display Template Page uploaded on $web site" -ForegroundColor Green  

                  }
          }
          catch
          {
              Write-Host $_ 
          }    
      }

   $web.AllowUnsafeUpdates  = $false;

  $web.dispose();
  $spsite.dispose();
 }

 try
 {
     [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Sharepoint")
     [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Sharepoint.Administration")

     $ConfigXmlPath = $scriptBase + "\Configuration.xml"
     Write-Host "Read the Config Values" -ForegroundColor Green 
     [Xml]$Config = Get-Content $ConfigXmlPath 

     AddPowerShellSnapin
     UploadDisplayTemplates $Config.Configuration.PublishingSite.URL # SiteCollection URL


 }
 catch
 {
     Write-Host "Custom Exception Happened on Main : " + $Error[0].Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red  
 }


 #stop-transcript
```

Reference: http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Upload-the-Display-Templates-into-SharePoint-2013-Using-PowerShell

In addition to above few more migration tool out there, you can try like [AvePoint](http://www.avepoint.com/products/sharepoint-infrastructure-management/sharepoint-migration/) and [Lepide](https://www.lepide.com/lepidemigratordocuments/sharepoint-to-office-365-migration.html) to accomplish this migration task easily and efficiently.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Why not just copy the file locally and then upload it again?